# Return JSON result of Alamofire request from function Using Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, alamofire, swift4

I have a function that returns the JSON result from the alamofire request. Initially the idea was to retrieve one of the values from the JSON result and store these in the array but each time I try to return either the JSON result or the populated int array, I get an empty result at the end of the function. The request is:

```
      func getSeats()-> JSON{
       var json : JSON = JSON()
       Alamofire.request(url , method: .get)
              .responseJSON{
                    response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                            json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    case .failure:
                 KRProgressHUD.showError(withMessage: "Could not retrieve reserved seats")
                    }
            }
           return json
        }
```

Initially, looking at the AlamoFire documentation, I tried to make use of the option of returning an array from the json result so I modified my code like this:

```
 func getSeats()-> [Int]{
   var json : JSON = JSON()
   Alamofire.request(url , method: .get)
          .responseJSON{
                response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                        json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                case .failure:
             KRProgressHUD.showError(withMessage: "Could not retrieve reserved seats")
                }
        }
       return json.arrayValue.map { $0["seat_no"].intValue }
    }
```

But this also returned an empty array which is why I had to change the function. The format of the JSON I receive is as follows:

```
 [
{
    "id": 1,
    "bus_id": 11,
    "seat_no": 6,
    "arrived_at": "2018-01-16 20:58:57"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "bus_id": 11,
    "seat_no": 27,
    "arrived_at": "2018-01-16 21:40:29"
}
```

]

I am very new to Swift and this is taking me forever to understand and work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are returning the empty `json` variable before it actually gets set to `JSON(response.result.value!)`. You shouldn't be returning the json like that, or anything at all really. Your function should take a closure argument instead, and the closure argument itself can take your json argument. Then you can execute the closure when you get the response back from the server and just pass it the parsed json.

I would recommend learning more about synchronous vs. asynchronous programming. Networking is asynchronous by default and it takes time for the data you're requesting to actually return in a response from the server.

Go research basic asynchronous programming, and networking with closures and completion blocks. Any basic iOS networking tutorial will cover these things.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Is there some kind of example I can take a look at?

Comment: @user1514567 Yes, all over the internet. Just do a google search.